# Getting "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" error while calling HTTPS SOAP service from C# Windows Service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

There is external SOAP API which supports requests over HTTPS only.
I am having Windows Service written in C# and calling this web service.

Below is the configuration on Windows Service's config -

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://myExtAPI.com/api_1234/service.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myExtAPI"
        contract="myExtAPI" name="myExtAPI" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myExtAPI">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

When call is made to API method I am getting this error - "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

I have written another web application. With same configuration, I am able to make successful call to API method.

**UPDATE**: Windows Service is running under Network Service account.

What am I missing? Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you load `https://myExtAPI.com/api_1234/service.asmx` from a web browser on the same machine running the Windows Service?

Comment: @mjwills It displays list of supported operations.